# Cannot push new branch from checkout

Tags: git, github

I was doing some work on a branch that comes from `develop`. I decided I don't want to use the branch anymore so did `git checkout develop` and then deleted it with `git branch -D branch1.0`. Later I decided to create the branch again (there were no changes to develop) with `git checkout -b branch1.0`. However when I now try to push the new branch I get this following error:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Why am I getting this? Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure but this may help: `git checkout master; git push --all origin;` `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your local branch is not in sync with the remote branch. 
You can either force push the local branch by using:

```
git push -f origin <branch>
```

Use this with care. **THIS WILL CAUSE THE REMOTE REPO TO LOSE THE CHANGES MADE BY OTHER COLLABORATORS.**

If you want to preserve the commits made in the remote, (after saving your local commits) you sync your local branch with remote using the following:

```
git pull --rebase
```

This will place all your local commits on top of newly pulled changes. Following this a push to your remote repo won't raise any flags.

Recreating the branch with same name raises flags on push/pull, if you **don't delete the remote tracking information**. To fix it delete the remote tracking info by using `git branch -d -r origin/<branch>` as well.

Comment: Why is it not in sync? If I do `git checkout develop` my local changes to develop. If I then create and checkout a new branch with `git checkout -b branch1.0` aren't I still in sync? Oddly I don't get the error if I create a branch with a name that wasn't used previously.